# Chat shortcut [metaso] expands to a URL that's missing a letter

Tags: bug, status-completed, status-declined, chat, magic-links

In chat, the short code `[metaso]` expands to `http://meta.stacexchange.com/` (no typo, the missing 'k' is the bug I'm reporting).

(And since this is too short a bug report, I'll note that I think that `[metaso]` should probably point to [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).)

Comment: Should I report this bug that there are both [status-completed] and [status-declined] on the same question?

Comment: @AwalGarg: Did you read the answer? The bug was fixed (hence `-completed`) while my parenthetical suggestion was `-declined`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the typo. That's fixed and will be soon deployed.

---

As for where `[metaso]` should point:

You may have missed that meta.stackoverflow.com has been split into two sites that reflect its former split personality as a Meta for Stack Overflow and one for the whole network.

As such, Meta Stack Overflow is now a **regular** child-meta, no special treatment. That means that on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow, `[meta]` should be used - `[metaso]` was more often than not used to indicate the **network** meta, so it now points to it.

`[metaso]` is officially deprecated (it isn't documented anywhere any more), and we did convert `[metaso]` to `[metase]` in old posts, but are keeping `[metaso]` around for a bit longer, for the places we may have missed and for those who still use it, for now.

Comment: I see. Removing `[metaso]` makes the most sense. I noticed that `[meta.SE]` points to this here site, which is intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: Double conflicting status tags not confusing enough.

Comment: @bjb568 - that's what happens when a post contains two, separate, feature requests.

Comment: I included the second only as an afterthought in order to get past the character minimum, but the answer is nonetheless appreciated.