# The [metaso] shorthand maps to "Meta Stack Exchange"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, chat, magic-links

Simple enough, in chat and in comments, when typing [metaso] the expected behavior is to get a link to [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). Instead, however, I get a link to [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is a test to see if [metaso] maps to Meta Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Exchange. I typed `[metaso]`.

Comment: It's answered over there, but it's not really a duplicate question, especially since the other one was mostly about a URL typo.

Comment: @BillyMailman: The point is that it is answered there. That's the duplicate policy (it also says "This question is answered here:" rather then "This is a duplicate of:")

Answer (score 5):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). `[metaso]` is Deprecated. See [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231084/226203) for the reasoning/more info.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the only question I've ever seen to be both [tag:status-completed] and [tag:status-declined] :P

Comment: @SecondRikudo: Looks like there are [a couple more like it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+status-declined).