# What are the magic links for Meta Stack Overflow, Meta Super User, and Meta Server Fault?

Tags: support, comments, per-site-meta, magic-links

I found out that the Meta Stack Overflow magic link is not included in [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242306/) nor [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/). There *are* generic links that follow the pattern `[<something>.se]` -> `[meta.<something>.se]`. For example, `[worldbuilding.se]` -> `[meta.worldbuilding.se]`.

However, sites with their own domain have their own type of links, for example, Stack Overflow is `[so]`.

I expected the magic link to follow the first pattern but `[meta.so]` does not actually work.

Through trial and error in the sandbox I found out that the the magic link that expands automatically is `[metaso]` by [trying most possibilities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment1170568_3122): `[meta.so]`, `[metaso]`, `[meta.so.se]`, `[meta.stackoverflow]`, `[meta.stackoverflow.se]`, and `[mso]`. **However**, that leads to Meta Stack **Exchange** instead which seems to be [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231084/).

Was hoping to find magic links to the metas and to to update the list. I also checked:

- Super User (base link: `[su]`). [I tried](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment1170569_3122): `[meta.su]`, `[metasu]`, `[meta.su.se]`, `[meta.superuser]`, `[meta.superuser.se]`, and `[msu]`
- Server Fault (base link: `[sf]`): [I tried](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment1170572_3122): `[meta.sf]`, `[metasf]`, `[meta.sf.se]`, `[meta.serverfault]`, `[meta.serverfault.se]`, and `[msf]`

None of these actually conjure up the link to the relevant meta. I can't even find any other documentation than the one I want to update.

Are there magic links for the metas of Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault? And if there are, what would they be?

Comment: As a side note: *why* are there two lists of all magic links? I only found a second one when I was trying to find more about a link to MSO.

Comment: Related: [the canonical list of magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q it's the second "this list" link in the post.